# difference between 姻族 and 姻戚

Tags: words, usage, nuances

What is the difference between 姻族 and 姻戚？

According to the definitions in the dictionary, they are pretty much the same. Would there be a time where I use one over the other?

If I look it up on Jisho:
姻戚

> 1. relative by marriage; affinity

and 姻族

> 1. in-law; relative by marriage

Furthermore, the definitions by goo dictionary：
姻戚

> 婚姻によってできた、血のつながりのない親戚。→姻族

and 姻族

> 婚姻によって親族になった者どうし。夫からみて妻方の父母兄弟など。民法では、三親等内の姻族を親族とする。姻戚。

Comment: according to my 角川国語辞典 they’re essentially synonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is definitely overlap in meaning and usage between the two words, 「姻戚」is more commonly used to refer to in-laws in a relatively narrower sense while「姻族」is more of a general reference to more than a few people, more like a generic kind of people. Since you have already looked them up in a dictionary, to tease out the usage nuances let's look at some examples.

**「姻戚」**

> また、宗麟の姻戚であった総大将、田原親賢が臼杵鑑速などの重臣達の反発を招いた結果だという説もある。([source](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/daimajin-b/e/8b348c99c86cf4bc492b7302b0325e83))
> There is the story that the supreme commander, Chikakata TAWARA who was a relative of Sorin triggered a protest from senior vassals including Akisumi USUKI. (translation from the original source)

> 秀政を一族の惣領として、父の秀重、姻戚の堀直政、利宗ら年長者たちが、秀政を盛り立てていた様子の一端が伺える。([source](http://seekfortune.wiki.fc2.com/wiki/%E5%A0%80%E7%A7%80%E6%94%BF))

> 桓武天皇皇女の高津内親王が妃を廃された後、姻戚である藤原冬嗣（嘉智子の姉安子は冬嗣夫人美都子の弟三守の妻だった）らの後押しで立后したと考えられる。([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A9%98%E5%98%89%E6%99%BA%E5%AD%90))

In all of the above contexts, the word is used as part of the phrase "as a relative of".

> ベントンは19世紀の多くの著名人と姻戚または血縁での関係があった。([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%88%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3))

> なかでも清正は若きころより武勇に優れていた利家を尊敬していたと言われ、事実、利家存命中は姻戚問題で利家邸、家康邸に各大名が集結する騒ぎとなった際も、姻戚問題を起こした当人にも関わらず利家邸に出席している。([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%89%8D%E7%94%B0%E5%88%A9%E5%AE%B6))

> 意次の人脈形成・田沼派拡大の柱は、姻戚関係の駆使である。(瀧澤中・『「江戸大名」失敗の研究: 政治力の差が明暗を分けた』)

In these examples, 「姻戚」refers to a kind of relation by marriage.

[**「姻族」**](https://makino-law.com/service/ex/column033-shinzoku/) appears to be more of a legal term, and is more often used to refer to a group of relative delineated by law or by marriage and/or blood relations.

> いわゆる「義理の〇〇」というのが「姻族」です。
> 姻族には、２パターンあります。
> １つ目は、結婚したことで家族になった人たちです。
> 配偶者の両親や、配偶者の兄弟姉妹などです。
> ２つ目は、血族の配偶者です。
> 兄弟姉妹の配偶者やおじおばの配偶者などです。
> いずれも、結婚によってつながった関係となります。

Of course we also see sentences with「姻族」where「姻戚」would be apt as well:

> 足利氏の姻族である上杉氏との縁戚関係などから、新田一族の惣領である新田義貞には従わずに、足利尊氏の後醍醐天皇からの離反、湊川の戦いなどに参加、その功で延元2年/建武4年（1337年）には名和氏の本拠である伯耆守護に任ぜられる。([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E5%90%8D%E6%99%82%E6%B0%8F))

In sum, I think it is more common to see「姻族」in legal contexts, referring to many people as opposed to one person.